# Want guidance in development of a website??

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to develop my own personal website.

Which one should I use, ASP or php?

I want the best performance in terms of page loading, rendering of web page, etc.

As I'm new to web development would you please guide me?

Any tutorial or book to follow?

Comment: Start out with this tutorial: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use, everything has purpose for something. It depends on what you're trying to do, how many visitors do you expect to have etc. Analyze everything beforehand then choose a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other things that you should consider before choosing the technology:

- Is your goal *just* to have a personal website, or actually develop it yourself ?
- Do you have any experience with other programming languages ?
- What kind of personal website is this?
- You should know that, basically, you can do everything you want with both languages, but do you really need them?
- About hosting, it's harder to find an ASP host especially if you're not willing to pay for your hosting.